# Get Fide-rated without revealing your birthday?

Tags: rating, fide

I noticed the Fide rating list is always published with the date of birth of the player. Is registering one's actual birthdate with Fide a requirement for a Fide rating? It is a major concern for me given the rise in cases of identity theft.

Comment: I agree with your point that collecting DOB details results in loss of your privacy. From my point of view, the DOB details are essential only for players competing in age category like Under 7, Under 11, Veterans aged above 60 and many more. If FIDE could hide the DOB section and keep it confidential, it would be wonderful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is.

Article 1.14 in [Regulations for Registration & Licensing of Players (effective from July 1, 2015)](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=180&view=article):

> All player's data are obligatory for online registration in FOA. For players registered by the National Rating Officers or the FIDE Rating Administrator, first name, last name, gender, date of birth, e-mail address and Federation are obligatory for a successful registration.

Comment: I am not sure if I should start a brand new thread. I am just curious if there are plans to remove the birthdays from official publications. Surely others are concerned about revealing their birthdays as well. Isn't there anything done about it? What can we do about it? I am ok with registering with birthdays. Just not fine with them revealing it to every hacker on the planet.

Comment: Date of birth is essential for differentiating between players with the same name. Arbiters need at least the year of birth when they report results for rating to FIDE and this is all that is published. The month and day are not published.

Comment: So, if register to a Fide-recognized National Chess Fundation and give as birthday "01-01-xxxx", where "xxxx" is my real birthyear but I'm not born the first of january, there is little chance my application will be refused. I cannot take advantage of it either (it doesn't change my age group), so it looks like a decent way to keep my birthdate confidential without "cheating", or does it ?

Answer (score 4):

> I noticed the Fide rating list is always published with the date of
>   birth of the player

That is not true. The full date of birth is now never published, although in the early noughties it was. Now just the year of birth is published.

Furthermore that is often also not published. When you register you can request that your year of birth is also not published. To verify you can go to the "[Advanced Search](https://ratings.fide.com/advseek.phtml)" on the FIDE rating website and search for female players from various Arab countries. If you do that you will see that for some of the countries many of the women have blank for their year of birth.

Example: [United Arab Emirates](https://ratings.fide.com/advaction.phtml?idcode=&name=&title=&other_title=&country=UAE&sex=f&srating=0&erating=3000&birthday=&radio=name&line=asc).

> Is registering one's actual birthdate with Fide a requirement for a
>   Fide rating?

FIDE require that to allow them to differentiate between two players with the same name. It does happen occasionally and then date of birth is essential. They don't need to publish even your year of birth. Once registered your FIN is enough to identify you in the system, and you can request even that is not published.

> It is a major concern for me given the rise in cases of identity
>   theft.

You are wrong to be concerned. Your full date of birth is never published, only the year, and you can request that not even that is published.